# How to make use of Fragments API in BASIC4Android

Tags: android-fragments, basic4android

Is it possible to make use of the Fragments API in BASIC4Android? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are not really needed in Basic4android. A regular Panel view will give you the same result.